# How to get elements in xml using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to print the "element" places in the XML file.  For example "data" and "country". After parsing the XML file, I want to print the names of these elements using "print". I can access child.tag. But I want to access data and country.

**My goal is to write a function if I am in the correct element.**

**Expected String Output: data, country.**

```
<data>
<country>
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country>
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
</data>
```

***this is my code:***

```
def parse_tree(ref):
    for child in ref:
        if child.text is not None and len(child) is 0:
            print(child.tag + " = " + child.text)
        parse_tree(child)


input_data = "data/xml.xml"
tree = ElementTree.parse(input_data)
root = tree.getroot()
parse_tree(root)
```

Comment: start by uploading a VALID xml file. The current one is not. Share the expected output. `data` contains `country` - what is the point to het both of them?

Comment: I want to print only <>'s contain. So, the data word should be print. The output should be the string "data".